# Run a program on Mac OS host from Windows running as parallels guest

Tags: parallels

On a MacBook Pro running Windows 7 in Parallels 7, I need to run a Unix Executable File on the Mac side via a command line invocation on the Windows side.  In Windows Explorer, I can use Open on Mac, but I need a way to do this via a batch file or anything else that can be expressed on a command line.  I was hoping that Parallels Tools might have a command that can do this, but I can't find anything.

This seems like it should be pretty straightforward, but my searches have turned up nothing.

I also tried creating an alias on the Mac side, which I added to my Applications folder.  I was hoping that it would appear in Start > All Programs > Parallels Shared Applications, which might allow me to access it with a batch file.  However, I don't see it.  I'm not sure what it takes to add new entries to Parallels Shared Applications.  Maybe a reboot would do it, but I have not tried that yet.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am looking the opposite.

Comment: No, I never did.  If you do find something (either direction), please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Platypus app might be able to help with this.  It wraps a shell script into a Mac App.  Unfortunately I can't get Parallels to provide access to the Platypus generated app the same way it provides access to the other Mac apps.